# Load 2 contiguous doubles into low-half of 2 sse registers

Tags: assembly, sse, intrinsics

I want to achieve this:

```
xmm0[0..63] = mem[0..63]
xmm0[64..127] = 0
xmm1[0..63] = mem[64..127]
xmm1[64..127] = 0
```

In fact, it doesn't have to be exactly like this. It's okay as long as:

```
xmm0[0..63] + xmm0[64..127] = mem[0..63]
xmm1[0..63] + xmm1[64..127] = mem[64..127]
```

How should I do this using xmm intrinsic?

Comment: I dont think there is a single instruction that will do that.

Comment: @Anycorn What is a reasonable way of doing this in multiple instructions?

Comment: you can just use two separate `movsd` (`_mm_load_sd` intrinsic).  Alternatively you could load the entire segment into first register to aggregate memory loads, then copy out the lower part to second register and subsequently zero out the lower part in first register.  But that will likely be worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply use the `_mm_set_pd` or `_mm_set1_pd` intrinsics and see what your compiler generates - it should be reasonably efficient, and if not then the generated code may give you an idea of how to improve on it with more explicit intrinsics, e.g.:

```
double d[2];

__m128d v0 = _mm_set_pd(d[0], 0.0);
__m128d v1 = _mm_set_pd(d[1], 0.0);
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by @Mysticial and @Anycorn, you can just use `_mm_load_sd`:

```
double d[2];

__m128d v0 = _mm_load_sd(&d[0]);
__m128d v1 = _mm_load_sd(&d[1]);
```

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best solution - answer updated.

Comment: you probably mean `_mm_load_sd(&d[0])`

Comment: @Anycorn: thanks - copy and paste with too much haste - fixed now.